# libgdx - blendFunc for brush line drawing? (additive/non-additive mixture)

Tags: opengl, libgdx, shader, brush, glblendfunc

I am drawing sprites to the framebuffer at each pixel for every step in a line between two points, but I have an issue with the blending:

[image]

I am currently using:

(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

Then, in my shader I do:

```html
if( color.a == 0 )
  color.rgb = 0;
```

However, if you look at the red and green star, you can see the "additive blending" that happens where the alpha is between interval of (0,1).

---

Without additive blending this 3D effect occurs:

[image]

---

**Is there a way to have additive blending of like colors, but avoid when colors are not matching?**

It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: I was thinking of just manually building a shader that passes the brush and framebuffer, but I dont understand the projection enough to get the right texcoords for both textures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using pre-multiplied alpha.

First you need to set up your texture properly. Draw it white on black like this: 
[image]

Then duplicate the texture's brightness into its alpha channel. In GIMP you can do this by right-clicking the layer, choosing Add Layer Mask, and then Grayscale Copy of Layer. It will look  kind of like this (as shown in Gimp):

[image]

Then you can recolor it's RGB channel if you like, although it's more versatile to leave it white and color it in your code.

In your code, when you draw the shape, use the blend function for pre-multiplied alpha:

```
batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

And draw it using the default SpriteBatch shader. After you've drawn the shape, switch back to regular alpha blending:

```
batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Sample game:

[image]

```
public class GameMain extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor{
    SpriteBatch batch;

    Texture star;
    Color color = new Color();
    Viewport viewport;
    int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    FrameBuffer fbo;
    boolean shouldClearFBO = false;
    boolean fboUpdated = false;
    OrthographicCamera fullScreenCamera;

    boolean touchDown = false;
    Vector2 touchLocation = new Vector2();

    int colorIndex = 0;
    static final int[] COLORS = {0xff0000ff, 0x00ff00ff, 0x0000ffff, 0xffff00ff, 0xff00ffff, 0x00ffffff, 0xffffffff};

    static final float SIZE = 150;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        star = new Texture("star.png");
        viewport = new ExtendViewport(800, 480);
        fullScreenCamera = new OrthographicCamera();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void resize (int width, int height){
        viewport.update(width, height, true);
        fullScreenCamera.setToOrtho(false, width, height);
        fullScreenCamera.position.set(width/2, height/2, 0);
        fullScreenCamera.update();
        fboUpdated = false;
        screenWidth = width;
        screenHeight = height;
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        if (!fboUpdated){
            fboUpdated = true;
            if (fbo!=null)
                fbo.dispose();
            fbo = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888, screenWidth, screenHeight, false);
            fbo.begin();
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            fbo.end();
        }

        color.set(COLORS[colorIndex]);

        fbo.begin();
        if (shouldClearFBO){
            shouldClearFBO = false;
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        }
        if (touchDown){
            batch.setProjectionMatrix(viewport.getCamera().combined);
            batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
            batch.begin();
            batch.setColor(color);
            batch.draw(star, touchLocation.x - SIZE/2, touchLocation.y - SIZE/2, SIZE, SIZE);
            batch.end();
        }
        fbo.end();

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(fullScreenCamera.combined);
        batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(fbo.getColorBufferTexture(), 0, screenHeight, screenWidth, -screenHeight);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        switch (keycode){
            case Input.Keys.SPACE:
                colorIndex = (++colorIndex) % COLORS.length;
                return true;
            case Input.Keys.X:
                shouldClearFBO = true;
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        viewport.unproject(touchLocation.set(screenX, screenY));
        if (pointer==1){
                colorIndex = (++colorIndex) % COLORS.length;
                return true;
        }
        if (pointer == 2){
            shouldClearFBO = true;
            return true;
        }
        touchDown = true;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        touchDown = false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        viewport.unproject(touchLocation.set(screenX, screenY));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Impressive!  When I try to duplicate, I am still getting the 3D brush effect using: batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);   I believe it may have something to do with the atlas I'm using that is created with the TexturePacker provided with libgdx.  I will keep trying and update here soon.

Comment: TexturePacker has a `premultiplyAlpha` option. So I think you can create your sprites the normal way (don't premultiply in the source image) and rely on TexturePacker to do it. Your source image would maybe be pure white in the RGB channel and look like my first image above in alpha channel. I haven't tried this.

Comment: It works!  Processing the image through GIMP as you outlined worked perfectly.  Although, I am not sure how to duplicate this method on Photoshop.  I know my problem though, my texture needs to have the RGB values match the alpha value.  Currently, they all have (1,1,1) for the color and the alpha is what changes.